# Can not import database in postgresql

Tags: sql, linux, database, postgresql

Hi i am using postgresql .  i tried to import a databsee by

```
$ psql arbles < app.arbles.com.15.08.2014.sql;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""
LINE 1:
        ^
```

it gives me an error ,

1. I firstly created my database arbles
2. then i gave one of my database user's full privilages of the database

> grant all privileges on database arbles to postgrestest;

3.then i tried the first command and it failed

my `app.arbles.com.15.08.2014.sql` file is in `/var/lib/postgres` i also moved it to different locations , but the same error occures.

```
postgrestest
```

is also a super user

i also thired with different solutions

```
   1. psql -h hostname -d databasename -U username -f file.sql
   2. \i C:/database/db-backup.sql
```

non of them worked , why is this happening  , please help me , thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the backup file is SQL file? How was it created?  If it was created using `pg_dump`, then use `pg_restore` to import the database.

Comment: @AleksG yes it was createed using pg_dump command

Comment: Try psql < filename dbname

Comment: @JohnBarça same error :(

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya What is the output of `file app.arbles.com.15.08.2014.sql`? How about `head -n 3 app.arbles.com.15.08.2014.sql | cat -A` ?

Comment: @CraigRinger could indeed be a BOM thing. I would also hexdump it.

Answer (score 0):

As you indicated that the backup was created using `pg_dump`, then, most likely, it's not a SQL file.  Instead of trying to execute SQL from that file, use `pg_restore` to restore it:

```
pg_restore -h hostname -d databasename -U username filename
```

Comment: it says pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive , actually create pg_dump in one server and then i upload via scp to another server , from that i do these things

Comment: @AleksG That's incorrect and misleading. `pg_dump` can create SQL dumps and does so by default. It only creates custom-format dumps if you pass `-Fc` (custom archive) or `-Fd` (directory).

Comment: @CraigRinger `pg_dump` can create dumps in SQL format, true, however `pg_restore` is supposed to be smart about the existing format - and import whatever it encounters.  In the past, I have had issues trying to execute the dump as a sql script while `pg_restore` worked fine.

Comment: @AleksG Well, newer versions will at least complain that `pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.`. Older versions just choke and die. It certainly doesn't do anything smart like run it through `psql`.